# StackoverflowException recursion and slow execution

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I have this code

```
private static void Count(List<DataRowSet> rows, int id, ref int count)
{
    foreach (DataRowSet row in rows) {
        if (row.parentId == id) {
            count++;

            Count(rows, row.Id, ref count);
        }
    }
}
```

and this class

```
public class DataRowSet
{
    public int Id;
    public int parentId;

    public DataRowSet(int id, int parent)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.parentId = parent;
    }
}
```

I want to count every child of a `List<DataRowSet>` with a specific id.

```
Count(dataList, 1, ref cnt);
```

That works but once I have more than 8000 entries in `dataList` a StackOverflow exception happens. Also the code is slow, it takes about 1.5 seconds to find all  entries.

What do I do to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `StackOverflowException` happens because your recursion is too deep. It works fine up to 8000, everything above is simply too much for the stack.
You can solve this by using a `Stack<DataRowSet>` and pushing items into it instead of recursively calling the function.

Looking at your `DataRowSet` class it seems like it's a flat list so there's a simple way to improve the performance by using a `ILookup<int, DataRowSet>`. That way - instead of iterating over the list over and over again - you can use the key to find any related items.

---

First you'll have to push the top-level items on your stack. This can be done like this.

```cs
Stack<DataRowSet> stack = new Stack<DataRowSet>(
    dataRows.Where(x => x.Id == id));
```

Using `dataRows.ToLookup`, you can group the entries by their `ParentId`.

```cs
ILookup<int, DataRowSet> dataLookup = dataRows.ToLookup(x => x.parentId);
```

After that you just have to loop through `stack` until it's empty while pushing new items that have the correct id.

```cs
while (stack.Count > 0) {
    DataRowSet currentRow = stack.Pop();

    foreach (DataRowSet rowSet in dataLookup[currentRow.Id]) {
        stack.Push(rowSet);
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about the `StackOverflowException` again and the performance has been increased as well.

All together your new function will look somewhat like this.

```cs
private static int Count(List<DataRowSet> dataRows, int id)
{
    int totalDescendants = 0;

    Stack<DataRowSet> stack = new Stack<DataRowSet>(
        dataRows.Where(x => x.Id == id));

    ILookup<int, DataRowSet> dataLookup = dataRows.ToLookup(x => x.parentId);

    while (stack.Count > 0) {
        DataRowSet currentRow = stack.Pop();

        foreach (DataRowSet rowSet in dataLookup[currentRow.Id]) {
            totalDescendants++;
            stack.Push(rowSet);
        }
    }

    return totalDescendants;

}
```

and can be called like this

```cs
int cnt = Count(dataList, 1);
```

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski If you take a look at my profile, I had the exact same problem a few months ago. I just copied the [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227062/generic-extension-method-to-count-descendants).

Comment: Btw are those 3 tick comming from a new Gui button I miised or manual typed?

Comment: I used that as a base and extended my function with it, thanks. The link helped too I might need that later